# Assistant simulation use male voice

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am a newbie creating a service with Dialogflow. Under Service Settings gear wheel there is an option called Speech. I have chosen a male voice (en-US-Wavenet-A).

When I click "See how it works in Google Assistant" on the right and run the simulation on my Google Home device it does not use the male voice. It uses a female voice. How do I make the simulation use the voice that I have specified?

Answer (score 1):

The "Speech" setting (which is only enabled if you have beta features turned on) is only valid for some of the integrations in Dialogflow. Specifically, if you're using the V2 API directly (ie - you're sending audio using the [Detect Intent API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis)) or if you're using the [telephony integration](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/telephony).

If you *just* plan to use Dialogflow for your Action on the Google Assistant - you shouldn't be making any changes in this section. These *only* apply to telephony and the API. And if you're developing for telephony or the API, then you shouldn't be testing with the Google Assistant simulator.

[image: Dialogflow console]

If you want to set the voice for an Action, you need to use the [Actions console](https://console.actions.google.com/) under the "Invocation" setting. The speech settings in Dialogflow *don't* apply to Actions with the Assistant.

[image: Actions console]

Comment: All I am doing is using an intent to recognise certain phrases and issuing a text response to answer that phrase. Are you saying that output is not spoken in the selected voice?

Comment: I've clarified the answer, but I'm saying that the voice selected in the Dialogflow settings only apply if you're developing for the DetectIntent API or if you're using Dialogflow's telephony integration. If you're developing for the Google Assistant, then you would use the controls in the Action console.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to how Dialogflow and Actions on Google fit together. Dialogflow has lots of doco at https://dialogflow.com/docs which I have been reading. As a result I have created an agent and set up a conversation that works well. Actions on Google has lots of doco at https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant which I have also been reading. What I haven't found is a good description of how the two hang together. In other words, to create the same conversation bot using a male voice do I use Dialogflow or Actions on Google or a bit of both? Sorry if I sound dumb.

Comment: To explain a bit more, I first created the entire conversation sequence in Dialogflow. Based on what you said I then created an Actions on Google project named the same and linked them. I set up all of the required fields in the Actions on Google project, including specifying a male voice, then clicked Add your First Action, Custom Intent, Build. It opened my Dialogflow project where I already have everything set up. Now what? I could not see what I am supposed to do next. I ran a test on the Assistant but it is still using the female voice.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know what I did but I somehow got the integration working. Not with the Actions on Google project that I was working on but another project called API-Project that magically appeared somehow. I then had to copy all of the Directory information and user information across to the new project and delete the old one.